# My idea of symbolic evaluator performing derivation on dynamic set of variables

Tags: lisp, lambda, symbolic-math

This will slightly link to my two previous questions  [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5639008/703103), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5628733/703103). I'm working on some symbolic evaluator which will be part of my project for simulation of electrical circuits. As someone had mentioned before I have turned my attention to lambda function and automatic function generation.

Task is easy. Let's define hash-table with some keys and values.

```
(defparameter *my-hash* (make-hash-table :test #'equal))

(defun get-symbol-var (x)
  (gethash x *my-hash*))

(defun symbol-var (x)
  (gethash (rest x) *my-hash*))
```

And here is main derivation function. Derivation is performed by lambda function generation process with some recursion. It is just a sample so it can perform derivation of variables, numbers and product of two inputs.

```
 (defun diff (exp var)
   #'(lambda (x) (cond 
       ((numberp exp) 0)       
       ((variablep exp)
         (if (same-variablep exp var) 1 0))
       ((productp exp)
          (+ (* (funcall (diff (second exp) var) x) ( eval-exp (third exp)))  
          (* (funcall (diff (third exp ) var) x) ( eval-exp (second exp)))))))) 

(defun diff-eval (equation var)
  (funcall (diff equation var) (symbol-var var)))
```

Some useful condition definitions

```
 (defun productp (x)
   (eql (car x) '*))

 (defun variablep (x) 
   (eql (car x) 'symbol-var))

 (defun same-variablep (v1 v2)
   (and (variablep v1) (variablep v2) (equal v1 v2)))
```

Because some variables can get out of derivation loop I defined special function for evaluation.

```
 (defun eval-exp (exp) 
   (cond
     ((numberp exp) exp)       
     ((variablep exp) (get-symbol-var (rest exp)))
     ((sump exp) (+ (eval-var-symbol (third exp))
                    (eval-var-symbol (second exp))))
     ((productp exp) (* (eval-var-symbol (third exp))
                        (eval-var-symbol (second exp))))))
```

Introducing some variables to database

```
(setf (gethash '(v 1) *my-hash* ) 1)
(setf (gethash '(v 2) *my-hash* ) 23)
(setf (gethash '(v 3) *my-hash* ) 1)
```

Testing equation d(v1*v2)/dv1

```
(setf *equation* '(* (symbol-var v 2) (symbol-var v 1)))
(diff-eval *equation* '(symbol-var v 1))
```

Am I doing it in a right way? Could this be done more LISP clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I suggest making the `diff` function do more processing of *exp*.** Instead of one big lambda function, return a closure for each conditional branch, with much of the processing including the recursive calls to `diff` done outside the lambda functions.

Doing more of the processing in `diff` may improve run-time performance as you move forward, particularly if the result of calling `diff` is reused. It can also benefit debugging, as many errors including those in *exp* will be caught when calling `diff` rather than later when invoking `diff-eval`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the existing free software Computer Algebra System Maxima.
It is comparatively easy to load into your Lisp image and you can use it
for much more elaborate tasks than just derivatives.

Download Maxima from here:
git clone git://maxima.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/maxima/maxima

Open a new lisp file in Emacs/SLIME and run this:

```
(require :asdf)
(setf asdf:*central-registry* (union '("/data/src/maxima/src/")
                     asdf:*central-registry*))
(require :maxima)

(in-package :maxima)
;; Documentation of how to convert between Lisp and Maxima:
;; http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_3.html
;; this sets the Maxima variable foo to contain a list x, y:
(msetq $foo #$[x, y]$)

;; The lisp function displa displays a maxima expression:
(displa '((MLIST SIMP) $X $Y $Z))

;; and this stores the derivation of log(z) into foo:
(msetq $foo #$diff (log (z))$)
;; => ((MTIMES SIMP) ((MEXPT SIMP) $Z -1) ((%DEL SIMP) $Z))
```